# Unchecked IDs displaying wrong ID.

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

While I was debugging, when there's an checked report, it shows its correct ID. But when there's an unchecked report below, it shows the ID of the checked report above it and it follows for every unchecked report below the checked one. The problem is in my query, and after changing some keywords, in the WHILE and SELECT statements, it still shows the wrong ID. Where could the problem be coming from?

```
If chk.Checked = True Then
            rpti = CType(oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblReportID"), Label).Text

            valsql2 = "INSERT INTO CompanyReportListTable(CompanyID, ReportID) Values (valCompanyId, rpti) WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID  <> " + rpti + " and CompanyID <> " + valCompanyId + ")"
            count += 1
            rptn = CType(oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblrptName"), Label).Text
            oExArgs.Add(rptn)
            'Response.Write(rpti + " - " + rptn + "<br/>")
        Else
            valsql2 = "DELETE FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE EXISTS(Select * FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID  = " + rpti + " and CompanyID = " + valCompanyId + ")"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `If` block:

```
' Set the rpti value
rpti = CType(oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblReportID"), Label).Text
' Use the rpti value
valsql2 = "INSERT INTO CompanyReportListTable(CompanyID, ReportID) Values (valCompanyId, rpti) WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID  <> " + rpti + " and CompanyID <> " + valCompanyId + ")"
```

And your `Else` block:

```
' Use the rpti value
valsql2 = "DELETE FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE EXISTS(Select * FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID  = " + rpti + " and CompanyID = " + valCompanyId + ")"
```

Since you never *set* the `rpti` value in the `Else` block, it's going to have whatever value it *already had*.

Just set the value to what you need before you use it.

Comment: Does that include the If block too? I should set rpti = to whatever value I need?

Comment: @RonRonmonsterererAnkrah: In the `If` block you already set it.  But you forgot to set it in the `Else` block.  You could set it once outside of the entire conditional structure, or set it within each branch of the conditional structure.  Either way, you should set it before trying to use it.

Comment: Yes thank you David! It worked! By setting rpti, it means that the label will be ready for any needed value, right?

Comment: @RonRonmonsterererAnkrah: Well, it means that `rpti` will have the value you want in your database query.  Whatever that means for labels and other UI elements after the fact is up to you.